# How to mask only select layers (i.e., exclude some layers from the mask)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, masking

is there a way to create a masking layer in QGIS (2.14) that will mask only certain layers, so that some layers (such as baselayer imagery or other) will be unaffected?

I'm using geometry generator as a symbol layer type to create dynamic, virtual buffers and want them to be masked when outside of a particular feature such as a property boundary

I have tried the mask plugin and also tried the inverted polygon symbol on a layer but cannot achieve desired effect as I can't find an option to exclude or include layers.